# Advice on database design for multiple catalogs

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a relatively simple database design that I will simplify here for the sake of brevity.

I have 4 tables => `Products, Product_Sizes, Stores, Catalogs`.

There are 6 stores and each store has it's own unique customized catalog, an assortment of different products and sizes that is chosen from the `Products` and `Product_Sizes` tables.

I am wondering how to best design the `Catalogs` table. My ideas are:

```
id store_id product_id product_size
1  1        53522      1
2  1        40299      1
3  2        43326      1
4  2        43326      2
```

OR

```
id store_id product_id product_sizes
1  1        53522      1
2  1        40299      1
3  2        43326      1,2
```

Each store has it's own unique (and only one) catalog, so a query to fetch all entries by store_id will result in that store's catalog.

Another approach would be to create another table of the combined products and product_size into it's each own unique table, let's call it `Products`.

```
id product_id product_size
1  1          1
2  1          2
3  1          3
4  1          4
```

This separate table gives me a unique id for all the possible products and their size variants. This would result in a single id per product for each `Catalogs` entry.

I would love to hear some critique and better suggestions as I feel this just isn't right and can't put my finger on how to better design this. Also, if we were to ever implement more than 1 catalog per store, I know this current design would cause me grief. Any feedback would greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me, I would create the `catalog` table as an entity table, with it's own id. If that catalog only belong to one `store`, I would add a `store_id` column as a foreign key.

I would then add a `catalog_products` table. This would have a foreign key to the `catalog` table, as well as a foreign key to the `products` and/or `product_sizes` table. (If a `product_size` belongs to only one `products` table, then just the `products_sizes` table.)

To resolve a many-to-many relationship, we typically add a third relationship table.

- a catalog has zero, one or more products (product_sizes)
- a product (product_size) appears in zero, one or more catalogs

The relationship table gets us "one-to-many" relationships, which we can represent:

- a catalog_product appears in exactly one catalog
- a catalog contains zero, one or more catalog_product
- a catalog_product is related to exactly one product
- a product belongs to zero, one or more catalog_product

Answer (score 0):

id store_id product_id product_size

```
1  1        53522      1
2  1        40299      1
3  2        43326      1
4  2        43327      2
```

Different product id for same product name with different sizes.